# Как использовать pip для разных версий python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, pip

Как можно использовать pip только для python 3.8.1, если у меня установлены 2 версии python?

Comment: Установлены как куда? Какая ОС? Есть ли виртуальные окружения?

Comment: Например, так: `python3.8 -m pip`, `python3.7 -m pip`. Или так: `pip3`, `pip2`. Всё зависит от того, как, куда и какие версии установлены.

Comment: @andreymal, окружения виртуального нету. Установлены на windows 10, скачаны с офиц сайта

Comment: @nomnoms12, пишет что python3.8 не является внутренней или внешней командой

Comment: `python3 -m pip` | `pip3` ?

Comment: @VictorVosMottorthanksMonica, к сожалению не поможет, т.к. обе версии python - версии 3.x.x Если точнее, то python 3.8.1 и python 3.7.4.

Comment: Ну как у вас python3.8.1 и называются python3.7.4?

Comment: А сейчас пип для какой версии ставит?

Comment: @Эникейщик, он ставит для версии 3.7.4

Comment: И если просто запустить python, то тоже будет 3.7.4? Поменяйте путь в переменной окружения PATH.

Comment: @Эникейщик, ну тогда каждый раз придётся менять путь, а это не слишком удобно. Можно ли как-то настроить PATH сразу на два pip?

Comment: Вы же хотели только для 3.8.1? Если нужно и туда и сюда, то можно полностью указывать путь к нужному pip. Или создать алиас, не знаю, есть ли такое в винде.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вызывайте pip через нужный python

```
/usr/local/bin/python3.8 -m pip install pip
```

Comment: Можно еще через pip2 (для python 2.x) или pip3 (для python 3.x)

Comment: Pip2, pip3 бывают перепутаны если стоят несколько версий одной ветки, а если обновить с --user...

Answer (score 1):

Вариант для Windows:

```
py -3.8 -m pip install package
```

Утилита py ([Python Launcher](https://docs.python.org/3/using/windows.html#python-launcher-for-windows)) под Windows позволяет запускать разные версии python в зависимости от аргумента, т.е. например можно запустить скрипт из командной строки с помощью нужной версии:

```
py -3.8 script.py
```

Это примерно аналогично `python3.8 script.py` на Linux и других unix-подобных системах.