# у меня две версии Python, pip устанавливает скрипты для старой версии, что делать?

Tags: python

у меня две версии Python, pip устанавливает скрипты для старой версии, что делать?

Comment: python 3.7.8 и python 3.1 стоит, нужно чтобы pip ставил скрипт на python 3.7.8, а он ... не знаю куда.

Comment: использовать virtual env?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как использовать pip для разных версий python?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1095365/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-pip-%d0%b4%d0%bb%d1%8f-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%85-%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%b9-python)

Answer (score 0):

> нужно чтобы pip ставил скрипт на python 3.7.8

Пишите так:

```
pip3 install ...
```